# VB Clear keyboard buffer

Tags: vb.net, barcode, barcode-scanner

i know my question seems very similar to others according to a buffer-clear issue... but here is a detailed description:

I have an motorolla handheld (bar-code scanner) which is reading barcodes over an tray tool.
The code is scanned by the traytool und is casted as an keystroke like a normal press on a key on a keyboard.

so i have an app in vb which should read a barcode and after that a second and than proceed the inputs.

after reading 12 chars/numbers my textfield should set the focus to an other textfield (2. barcode) so i check onChange the length and than set the focus to the next textfield.

if there is a malicous barcode or a barcode which contains more than 12 characters/numbers the second textfield will be filled with all chars after the 12. char from textfield 1.

i have no control over the scan behaviour or the keydown event of the scanner trigger... nothing possible.
also there is no termination symbol in the input data which signals me that one block is ending here.

so how is it possible to clear the buffer of the virtual keyboard of the scanner ?!
any suggestions?

Comment: Only use one textbox.  Copy "good" data from there to other controls, throw away "bad" data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downloading the manual for your scanner to find the configuration codes.  They are typically a set of special barcodes that can be scanned to set properties such as allowed symbologies.  What you will want to do is set the scanner so that it appends a CRLF, Tab, or other terminator for your data.  That way you can act upon the end of the barcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TWAIN to handle the scanning thought i am not sure whether it supports Motorola. Try to download some TWAIN libraries and in-cooperate them with your project.